# powershell command output logging in batch script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, echo, command-prompt

I need to write this command to a bat file in a specific location:

```
echo PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" >> "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\StartupLog.txt" >> c:\myscript.bat
```

When I run this command it will only write `PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in `myscript.bat`.

I need to write the full command with the output file logging. Is this possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) and apply it as follows:

```
echo PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" ^>^> "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\StartupLog.txt" >> c:\myscript.bat
```

**Proof** (`copy & paste` from a `cmd` window, so lines are wrapped):

```
d:\bat> type myscript.bat
The system cannot find the file specified.

d:\bat> echo PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" ^>^> "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\2\StartupLog.txt" >> myscript.bat

d:\bat> type myscript.bat
PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" >> "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\T
emp\2\StartupLog.txt"

d:\bat>
```